# Why srcset not work normally on MacBookPro(or maybe retina monitor caused?)

Tags: html, css, responsive-images, srcset

First of all, before asking, I have read lots of articles about **responsive images** and **srcset**, so I am sure the codes with demo absolutely correct, but result does not as expect.

We can open MDN [Demo](https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/html/multimedia-and-embedding/responsive-images/responsive.html) for testing. And let's keep eyes on part of html code below:

```html
<img srcset="elva-fairy-480w.jpg 480w,
              elva-fairy-800w.jpg 800w"
      sizes="(max-width: 600px) 480px,
            800px"
      src="elva-fairy-800w.jpg" alt="Elva dressed as a fairy">
```

On my `MacBookPro 2018` with internal monitor, Whatever the width I have set any, it always load `elva-fairy-800w.jpg`

If document width less than 600px, it should load `elva-fairy-480w.jpg`.

I have do lots of test about media queries, viewport meta edited, but nothing changed.

Above tests I just notice that srcset not working normally, but `picture` and another what I have made a new [demo](https://public.whidy.net/demo/responsive-html-images/index.html) with css media queries works fine(In my demo, if width set < 600px, body font color changes to **red**)

At last, I send my demo to my friend, everything goes well, different between us is the computer, or monitor.

After that I connect a external monitor(1080p), amazing things happened, the result is ok!

So I am confused about, why macbookpro not work good, is it retina caused?

What make me surprised more is, I drag browser form external monitor to macbookpro monitor, with chrome devtool network pannel opened. We can see a new request of `elva-fairy-800w.jpg`.

I upload a video on youtube: [srcset not work properly](https://youtu.be/EkbddJ0yu24), you can see it in the video.

By the way, if I do tests with `Emulated Devices` also good.

So why macbookpro has `srcset` problem?

What I have read:

- [Responsive images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Viewport_concepts)
- [<picture>: The Picture element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture)
- [Beginner's guide to media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Media_queries)
- [Viewport concepts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Viewport_concepts)
- [Using the viewport meta tag to control layout on mobile browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag)
- [A tale of two viewports](https://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html)
- [Responsive img gets wrong images from srcset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51290584/responsive-img-gets-wrong-images-from-srcset)

Comment: have you tried using the `<picture>` tag for responsive images instead?

Comment: In MDNoffical demo, <picture> tag works fine. My local test file also good for <picture> tag, but not good for img srcset.

Answer (score 0):

Is it retina caused? Yes, it is.

The most common pixel density for retina is 2x, meaning there are 2 times the number of pixels per inch. That's the reason why your MacBook loads the larger image. (c.f. https://www.listrak.com/blog/responsive-design-retina-images)

Comment: Even though retina is 2x, I still wonder why about 2 point:

1. Why other media queries work well?
2. If I set < 300px, is it srcset should works fine? But actrually not.

Comment: 1. The retina display calculates with "logical" pixels, where one logical pixel = four physical pixels (it may be even more). So media queries are treated as if the pixel density corresponds to the logical pixels. 2. If the image is cached it will not be replaced by a smaller one / or your retina display has an bigger density than 2x.

Comment: Still disunderstand about that. I've sent a image with my test here "[srcset research on MacBook Pro](https://imgur.com/a/SMxEEz4)", we can see in image that I set scaled resolution 1920px, and native resolution is 2880, [reference](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP776?viewlocale=en_US). So it 1.5X now, if webpage srcset media queries < 600px, after computed, when document scale to less than 450px, it should work, am I right? But what I uploaded image shows that even 150px, It load `elva-fairy-800w.jpg`, and I have always checked **disable cache**.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't figure out the difference between logical pixels and css pixels. 2x graph should be used in this example. Try this:

```html
<img
  srcset="elva-fairy-960w.jpg 960w, elva-fairy-1600w.jpg 1600w"
  sizes="(max-width: 600px) 480px, 800px"
  src="elva-fairy-1600w.jpg"
  alt="Elva dressed as a fairy"
>
```